# Logstash Plugin not getting installed

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-14.04, logstash, apache-kafka

I am trying to install the **kafka output plugin for logstash 1.5.0.beta1**.
I had done it previously using the command

```
$LS_HOME/bin/plugin install logstash-output-kafka
```

as given on the logstash website.

But now the installation is giving me the following error:

```
Clamp::UsageError: No such sub-command 'logstash-output-kafka'
     signal_usage_error at /home/madhura/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.3/lib/clamp/command.rb:103
  find_subcommand_class at /home/madhura/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.3/lib/clamp/subcommand/execution.rb:28
  instatiate_subcommand at /home/madhura/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.3/lib/clamp/subcommand/execution.rb:17
                execute at /home/madhura/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/clamp-0.6.3/lib/clamp/subcommand/execution.rb:10
                    run at /home/madhura/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/runner.rb:144
                   call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271
                    run at /home/madhura/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/lib/logstash/runner.rb:171
                   call at org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271
             initialize at /home/madhura/Softwares/logstash-1.5.0.beta1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.18/lib/stud/task.rb:12
```

Kindly help me find the reason and install the plugin

Answer (score 2):

Edit: as of Logstash 1.5.0 Kafka input/output is natively supported, see:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-kafka-intro

In logstash-1.5.0.beta1 (through 1.5.0.rc2 at least), the Kafka input/output plugins ship with the base logstash install:

```
.../logstash-1.5.0.beta1$ ./bin/plugin list | grep kafka
logstash-input-kafka (0.1.5)
logstash-output-kafka (0.1.3)
```